# Dealing with Stack Overflow's 'seo' tag

Tags: discussion, seo, stack-overflow

The [SEO tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) on Stack Overflow is in quite a poor state - many of the questions are off-topic for SO, with less than half closed and migrated here.

So I'm wondering if there is something we can do to encourage users to ask these questions on Pro Webmasters in the first instance? Auto-migration would never work, since there are valid programming questions (ie. contain code) that are asked in the interests of SEO.

Perhaps a message or warning could be displayed for anyone using the SEO tag, with an option to migrate the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think we should have a separate site for SEO, since it is itself a separate industry, pretty much lol. Something like: www.seopro.com or www.proseo.com (I haven't checked availability.)

Comment: @Jason: there is an SEO proposal in Area 51 (in fact it was the [very first proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1)). Pro Webmasters was initiated much later and overtook it. Since PW is already 50% SEO, splitting that into a separate site would probably kill PW. What we ought to do is try and get some more SEO professionals using PW.

Comment: True. Well, I'm an SEO pro, we do consulting for businesses 'round here - so I'll let some people know about the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cross-post of this question to StackOverflow meta to share your concern with that site's moderators seems like the safest bet, given that there seems to be a general opinion that SE sites "should not be Yahoo Answers" (and that feature sounds strikingly similar to Y!A's implementation... which, IMHO, is actually not a bad thing)